# VueJS NuxtJS HTTP requests after refresh token call do not update vue components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, refresh-token, vue-reactivity

So I have this issue where I am sending a refresh token request to my Laravel API backend and after receiving it back to my NuxtJS frontend app I am repeating calls that failed but of course, Vue components are not updating.

This is how it looks like - code that catches the failed requests

```
$axios.onError(error => {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        app.$auth.useRefreshToken().then(() => {
          error.config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${app.$auth.accessToken}`
          $axios.request(error.config)
        })
      }
    })
```

Code that sort of concatenates promises and that also works fine.

```js
 useRefreshToken() {
    if (this.refreshTokenPromise instanceof Promise) {
      return this.refreshTokenPromise
    }

    const refreshTokenPromise = this.PKCERetrieveTokens({
        grantType: 'refresh_token',
        refreshToken: this.$store.state.auth.refreshToken
      }).then(() => this.setRefreshTokenPromise(null))

    this.setRefreshTokenPromise(refreshTokenPromise)
    return refreshTokenPromise
  }
```

So when I am making my two failed calls again with a new token they are fine however because they are repeated in this global interceptor it sort of does not connect with the original component where that failed, and does not trigger the component to update if that makes sense.

Is there any good way of solving that? What do I do here?

Comment: The promises in onError are ignored, there's no way how the outside world could know that requests were retried. You'll need to handle this in axios interceptor, not onError. You may want to check first  how retry is implemented in axios

Comment: hey @EstusFlask, thanks for quick response, `$axios.request(error.config)` it is in my example, where I repeat them. I do them twice. So what is happening: I load the component and the original requests fail. I catch that in my interceptor, get a new token, and automatically repeat failed requests. However I do not know how to tell the component that I've repeated them and I do not want to refresh the page as it looks a bit bad in my opinion.

Comment: @EstusFlask just to add, `onError` is an interceptor helper from NuxtJS.

Comment: I mean that $axios.request(error.config) is detached from the outside, it doesn't matter if you do it or not in onError. onError is just the wrong place for what you try to do. Btw "Code that sort of concatenates promises" - this will cause memory leaks, don't use infinite promise chains

Comment: I see, didn't check it. Then you probably need to just return  $axios.request(error.config) from there. Also app.$auth.useRefreshToken() . Use async-await if this helps

Comment: I will do the async await combo, that's a good idea. I just need to get that to work first. That's the thing - I am already retrying requests from within the global interceptor. It will handle new token stuff if I am logged in and my token went bad. The only problem I have is that I do not know how to update the vue component after that happens. I don't want to refresh the page after every 5 minutes.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you try to redo all completed requests on the page when a token is updated? Then a big part is missing here, Axios alone isn't supposed to help with that

Comment: Yep, so the flow is as follows: I land on my let's say admin page where I see all the users, however token has expired. At this point axios sees, "oh I have 401 and I am supposed to be logged in" and it makes a call to get a new token. I get a new token and straight away make all the calls that failed before I got the new token. Now all of that works fine - I am missing the bit where I can put the new data to the components. Or maybe I should keep track in vuex of what has failed and then just fire that again somehow?

Comment: So I am trying to retry all the failed requests (the ones failed due to expired token).

Comment: Yes, tracking them is a choice. Probably cached results need to be made null in a store to mark them as loadable, or there could more complex caching strategy, like stale-revalidate pattern (you don't want data to disappear in a view during a refresh). Speaking of which, possibly the case for Swrv or Vswr, but I'm not sure how well they play with Nuxt. Any way, that's it, this is not a case for Axios, as it provides promise control flow, so it's 1 response in the end, it needs some reactive wrapper to consistently handle this behaviour.

Comment: @EstusFlask eh this is getting more and more complicated. I think I will move that data into store rather than keeping it in the components. I will then catch failed requests there
. I do have easy access to store (it's persisted and encoded) so after the token retrieval I will just read which store methods failed. Or something. Moving to store should solve reactivity issue.

Comment: @EstusFlask how would you approach that if ai may ask? I thought about tracking but seems to be a bit awkward. How does Facebook or reddit do it?

Comment: I wouldn't look at big guys because I'm pretty sure they are in maintenance hell.  You could implement simple tracking in global store by having a map of stale state keys in a state, so working app would have `_cache: { foo: [1], _staleCache: { foo: [1] }, ...`, and the state is publicly available through getters, `foo(state) { return state._cache._foo ?? state._staleCache._foo   }`, then when you need to refetch, you set mark `foo` as stale, `state._cache._foo = null`, watch for shallow `_cache` changes and trigger `foo` action when _cache._foo is empty and _staleCache._foo is not.

Comment: Then set _staleCache._foo = _cache._foo when action is successful. Then it will become gradually more complicated if actions accept params, e.g. fetch similar state entries with different ids, you'll need to keep a map of params that were used by actions and map them to respective cache entries that correspond to action results. This is how stale-while-revalidate may work, more or less. As I said, you may try  Swrv or Vswr

Comment: @EstusFlask ah I did look at it a bit wrong I guess, I didn't realize Swrv is the name of the package. Oh, well. Sorry for million questions but I am trying to learn something while I am at it. I think I see now, If I were to do it manually I would have to have a key in my state which would reflect stale keys in my state. That part I get but how do I determine if they are stale? Is there any literature you could point me to?

Comment: I would like to filly understand the whole process as this concept is entirely new to me. But by the looks of it, this is the way to go.

Comment: No specific literature, just common reading about stale-while-revalidate and its implementations. `_cache._foo === null && _staleCache._foo !== null` will be a flag that cache entry is stale and needs to be refetched, needs to be checked in a watcher, https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch . In my suggestion, _cache and _staleCache entries are set to fit this logic. You can have a separate _stale map of bools and set it accordingly but in this case it would be exhaustive.